# accessing a patched object in @classmethod

Tags: python, unit-testing, class-method, patch, python-mock

I would like to set a side-effect to a patched object in the `TestCase.setUpClass()` method so that the side-effect will persist throughout the tests without having to set it per test via `setUp()`.

How can I access the patch in a `@classmethod`?

```
@patch('my_module.auxiliary_module', autospec=True)
class TestMyModule(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # how can I access the patch here to set a side-effect?

    def test_a(self, mock_auxiliary_module):
        # here the patch is accessible
```

An example of what I'd like to do in `setUpClass()`:

```
mock_auxiliary_module.some_func.side_effect = lambda x: {'a': 2, 'b': 5}[x]
```

Comment: What kind of information would you like to retrieve from patch object? Whether it class-data or instance-data?

Comment: I coulnd't access the patched object in `setUp()` as well!<br>I guess whatever solves the question above will also solve the `setUp()` case

Comment: @AlexG.P. see my edit above - I want to set a side-effect, not retrieve anything from the patched object

Answer (score 0):

Make it a class attribute, so that you can access it with `cls.my_obj` in `setUpClass`, or `self.my_obj` in other test methods ?

I'm not familiar with patching, so this might be way off the mark.